# dynamically change row counts in tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with total sales as rows and regions as columns. The dashboard contains filters by region. I want to add a total counts field which calculates the total sales for the regions selected in the filters. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

drag sale in text

[image]

change measure to count

[image]